# No idea annotations attached to the jdk

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-6

I have installed Java 8 to my IntelliJ Idea. I have added path to jdk in Idea. And when I start my project I see that message:

> no idea annotations attached to the jdk
>   [image]

What I need to do to fix that?

Comment: Did you click the "Attach annotations" link over there on the right?

Comment: @Makoto Nothing happened

Comment: Does File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... help?

Comment: @y.bedrov No. But I have reinstall studio for 3 times and this is working!

Comment: I'm stuck on this too. Updated to Android Studio 3.2 and this warning occurs. Tried Invalidate Caches / Restart, tried clicking Attach annotations. Can't figure it out. Also, getting IDE exceptions about the androidAnnotations.jar file.

Comment: No Idea! are you mixing Jdk versions? I see Java 8 and Jdk 1.6 in your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.

The solution is somewhat obvious, just click on the banner and the message would go away. But of course, we want to know what does this do. Someone already asked this in the intelliJ community:

*It adds jdkAnnotations.jar to the JDK configuration*

*This JAR provides external annotations for JDK methods.
Magic Constant is one of the inspections using these annotations*

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002764859-No-IDEA-Annotations-attached-to-the-JDK-1-8-Some-Issues-Will-Not-be-Found

Unfortunately, I was unable to find out where that can be manually added (or at least reviewed) in a newer version of intelliJ